# SearchforRecord Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I'm having a lot of difficulty with a SearchForRecord vba statement.  It is a combobox called cboProjectNumber with a list of project numbers that is supposed to navigate to the record selected in my table based on a short text field called Project Number.  I had it previously as an embedded macro created with a wizard with the same criterion (see picture), but when I tried using VBA instead (as I wanted to set the combobox to null after jumping records) I keep getting Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch and my table does not change records.

```
DoCmd.SearchForRecord "", "", acFirst, "[Project Number] = " & "'" & Screen.ActiveControl & "'"
cboProjectNumber.Value = Null
cboProjectSubCategory.Requery
cboResDev.Requery
cboSingleorMulti.Requery
cboProjectSize.Requery
cboZoning.Requery
```

[image: Embedded Macro]

What's going on??

Comment: Does it need to be `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: The first parameter takes a [number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.searchforrecord), the default would be -1.

Comment: It seems to complain when I try changing my double parentheses to single.  

It's weird, in the embedded macro it seems to require using the double equals sign as part of the where clause to work.  I just can't figure out in my VBA where clause is the same, and if not, how to change the statement so it works.

Comment: Thank you Warcupine, that was the fix!  I changed the first parameter to -1 and now it works.  I can't seem to figure out how to select your answer as the answer though (maybe I'm too new to Stack Overflow to have this privilege?).

Comment: Comments are not answers. You can flag it as useful but does not add rep. @Warcupine could write an answer.

Comment: There is a macro SetValue action - have to click "Show All Actions" on macro design tab to make it available. But I never use macros and recommend switching all code to VBA.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!